# Moving numbers in a list based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Program is suppose to move numbers around based on a the "pivot" value. All numbers in front of the pivot value on the list need to be less than or equal to the pivot value and all numbers behind the pivot value are greater than the pivot value. (Python 3.x)

```
a = [1,4,3,7,4,7,6,3,7,8,9,9,2,5]
print("Original List")
print(a)
pivot = 4 #or select any number from the list
b = list(a)

for i in range(len(a)):
    pivotIndex = b.index(pivot) #gives index of pivot through every iteration

    if a[i] > pivot:

        b.insert(pivotIndex+1,a[i])

    elif a[i] <= pivot:

        b.insert(0,a[i])

print("New List")
print(b)
```

The problems are that I can't figure out how to remove the original number once it has been moved and in a list like this where there are duplicates of the pivot value, when a number comes up that is equal to the pivot it moves it to the front and treats it as the new pivot. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Are you implementing quicksort?

Comment: No, I've never used it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to create the new list and use `enumerate` to ensure that you are only counting elements that do not have an index at the pivot:

```
a = [1,4,3,7,4,7,6,3,7,8,9,9,2,5]
pivot = 4
new_l = [c for i, c in enumerate(a) if c > a[pivot] and i != pivot] + [a[pivot]]+[c for i, c in enumerate(a) if c <= a[pivot] and i != pivot]
```

Output:

```
[7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 5, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.pop(index)` to get the value at index and remove it in one action:

```
numbers = [2,3,4,5,7]
print(numbers)
n = numbers.pop(2)
print (n)
print (numbers)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
4
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

The indexing is zero-based.

Read:
[list.pop([i])](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list. (The square brackets around the i in the method signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation frequently in the Python Library Reference.)